# How to Sub query using BQL in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

We want to translate this SQL to BQL in Acumatica with the use of PXFilteredProcessingJoin, how can we do this?

```
SELECT * FROM BAccount WHERE BAccount.BAccountID in (Select CQHRISTimekeepingBundyClock.Employee as 'BAccountID' from CQHRISTimekeepingBundyClock)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you don't need Sub Select in this case.
Inner join will be enough here.

```
PXSelectJoin<BAccount,
InnerJoin<CQHRISTimekeepingBundyClock, On<BAccount.bAccountID, Equal<CQHRISTimekeepingBundyClock.employee>>>,
Where<...>>
```

As for sub selects in general, you can do it in Acumatica using PXProjection attribute or PXDBScalar attribute.
Check ARInvoice or ARInvoiceWithDL DACs for reference.

Comment: Can we use it in processing pages? We want to display the results in the grid of processing page and we are using PXFilteredProcessingJoin.

Comment: Sure, just replace PXSelectJoin by PXFilteredProcessingJoin